# Why are generally two of three effective masses identical?

Tags: mass, semiconductor-physics

In indirect semiconductors, the effective mass of electrons depend on the direction. There are three principle directions pointing away from the global energetic minimum in which the effective masses are usually defined. Two of these three masses are usually identical. Is there a hand-waving explanation for this? I only found the following statement: "If the group of k_0 contains at least a threefold axis, two of the mass values are identical" (Landolt-Börnstein, Numerical Data and Functional Relationships in Science and Technology, Semiconductors, Group IV Elements, Lattice Properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it contains a threefold axis (of rotational symmetry) then in the plane perpendicular to the rotational axis two vectors (say x and y) will have the two dimensional irreducible representation (generally $E$ in point groups) - and the representation for x and y will include both x and y and it will be impossible to split up x and y into different one dimesional representations. Thus $E$ represents (x,y) and the two directions will behave similarly.

Thus to go to your question the effective mass will be the same in x,y directions, but different in the z direction (which is the axis of the threefold rotation).

Hope this is useful and sorry if it is just too 'hand-wavy'